# What causes AppleScript error 1721 when trying to execute Python3 file?

Tags: terminal, applescript, python

I'm trying to make AppleScript to execute Python 3 script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@"
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

but I'm still getting an error 1721. I tried different types of file as well as changing Command Line command from:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@
```

to

```
/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@"
```

Both commands:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@
```

and

```
/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@"
```

Run OK, when typed directly within the Terminal.

Comment: I'm no expert on Applescript/shellscript, but usually you don't need to `tell` anything to run `do shell script` you just do it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, FYI `do shell script` is an AppleScript built-in and runs in the context of `tell current application` and is only explicitly needed when `do shell script` is set within another applications `tell` _block_ to avoid throwing an error. That said, it's usually a non-fatal error and AppleScript then executes it in a `tell current application` _block_.  Terminal has a `do script` _command_. Maybe the OP is confused on which to be using, however I can't say why for sure because the OP is lacking some details.

Comment: I see you are running in an `on run {input, parameters}` _handler_. Are you doing this in Automator or Script Editor? If the latter, that's why you are getting the error. An `on run {input, parameters}` _handler_ doesn't run within Script Editor.

Comment: You said "but I'm still getting an error 1721". Is the any _message_ with the _error_ or is it just `error "" number -1721`?

Comment: Instead of cross posting the same question to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960937/what-causes-applescript-error-1721-when-trying-to-execute-python3-file provide an answer to the questions I asked in the comments. REF: **I see you are running in an `on run {input, parameters}` _handler_. Are you doing this in Automator or Script Editor?** and **You said "but I'm still getting an error 1721". Is there any message with the _error_ or is it just `error "" number -1721`?** Please put the issue in proper context so we can troubleshoot this better. Do not cross post to multiple SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you  [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) on the basis of your answers I was able to figure out the problem.

That's the correct script for AppleScript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@"
end tell
```

This script is for Automator to run AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/UserName/Desktop/PyHello.py $@"
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Also following shebang is needed in initial Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: You said, "That's the correct script for AppleScript:" followed with a `do shell script` _command_ within a `tell application "Terminal"` _block_, **and that is not the proper usage as Terminal does not understand the `do shell script` _command_!** It actually throw a non-fatal error and then AppleScript reruns the `do shell script` _command_ within its proper context, which is a `tell current application` _block_. **In other words, there is no practical reason to run it as you've shown, it's improper and poor coding!**

Comment: You do not need and should not use the `do shell script` _command_ within a `tell application "Terminal"` _block_! If you're trying to run a _command_ in Terminal via AppleScript or Automator and AppleScript so as to see its _output_ **then use the `do script` _command_** not the `do shell script` _command_. If you do not need to see the output of a _shell command_ then use the `do shell script` _command_ by itself outside of any `tell` _block_ other then `tell current application`. That's the proper way to do it.